# Create a scheduled task in every language

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, multilingual

i try to add a task with 
*schtasks /create /tn bla /tn "c:\blabla.exe" /st 04:00:00 /sd 01/01/2011* **/sc daily**

this works on english Versions.
But, when i try to fire that command on german Systems it needs the "/sc täglich".

Is there a way to change that command that it runs in every language?

Comment: good Q, but probably should be on superuser.com

Comment: oh okay. i didn't know that there is such a site :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I argue that a "superuser" only has to handle the language of his own system (and those of his coworkers). It's the programmer who has to solve this problem for every language. It would have been nice to see an answer here on stack overflow.